# CPU and GPU Mining

Tags: cpu-mining, gpu-mining

Can you mine using your CPU and GPU?  When I am running ccminer GPU for nVidia, the program is only using the GPU to mine.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will most likely need to run two mining programs at once. (this isn't really a big deal, you will just need to open another command prompt to start the other one)

The ccminer-cryptonight that you are using was forked from someone elses code that originally WAS a cpu-miner but after reading the README.txt it doesn't look like there's a way to specify you want to ALSO use your CPU.

I haven't used this specific CPU miner for XMR but claymore seems to know his stuff for everything else he's written (if its a he)
https://github.com/nanopool/Claymore-XMR-CPU-Miner